# Stop Wayland / Sway from intercepting virtual console hotkey (Alt-F1, etc)

Tags: wayland, virtual-consoles, sway

I am using Wayland / Sway on Arch with the x-compatibility layer enabled and it is consuming keystrokes, notably the Alt-F1 hotkey necessary to get to a virtual console.

I suspect it is the x-layer that is doing it. (The keystroke is not bound in any of my configuration files).

How can I stop the graphical system from intercepting this keystroke?